# Fluid template: div offset

Tags: html, css

I've done this template:

[image]

(It's 100% scale)

Now it's 300% scale:

[image]

How to fix it? I want it to automatically adjust to the scale.

Here is CSS sandbox with this template: http://cssdesk.com/KPQwa

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can't access you'r template with navigation.
I get only the default one that is also on main page (http://cssdesk.com/).
Can you add right link or instead send jsfiddle link.

Comment: this is my template on the right side. You can zoom in / out and see the result. :)

Comment: Ah okay. Sorry looks like i did understand you wrong. By saying "automatically adjust to the scale" do you mean that you want your website to be responsive?

Comment: probably "fluid". I'm sorry if I'm wrong in the title. Example: http://css-tricks.com/examples/PerfectFluidWidthLayout/